# A-frame, controlling 'hand-controls' with keyboard/mouse

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

Is this possible?

Since my understanding of aframe and how entity-component system works is severely lacking, i simply tried to call one of the hand methods in the hand-controls component.

```
// I want to see a grip event 
handControllerDOMElementReference.components['hand-controls'].onGripDown()
```

This achieved nothing. When tracing everything that happens in the 'hand-controls' component it looks like the gestures and animations are all called. But nothing happens, so i'm assuming i'm doing this completely the wrong way.

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `hand-controls` responds to events that some component like `oculus-touch-controls` or `vive-controls` emit, see https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/hand-controls.js#L57

It is certainly possible to have other components provide those events, such as
https://github.com/chenzlabs/gearvr-controls
or ryanbetts aframe-daydream-controller-component

Perhaps you can either manually generate those events, or better yet create a component that generates them when applied?

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the grearvr component, see how they provide events, see if i can do it the same way.